# mysql joning results with multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say i have a table called player

```
profileid, player
```

and a table called bank

```
id, profileid, player, item
```

lets say i have the follow entry for `player`

```
table player: [1, verro]
```

lets say i have 5 entires into bank like this:

```
table bank: [1, 1, verro, "gold bar"]
table bank: [2, 1, verro, "gold bar"]
table bank: [4, 1, verro, "gold bar"]
table bank: [5, 1, verro, "snake"]
```

how can i build a query with the following conditions?:

select player with the name verro then sum up how many gold bars he has?

the result should be: `["verro", 3]`

i was attempting to do this:

```
select *, count(item) from player_deposit bank
join player_attributes pa on bank.player = pa.player
where LOWER(bank.player) = "verro" && bank.item = "Gold Bar"
```

but did not work for me, and was slow.

Comment: Do you really need the join? if yes, index on player column on both table would help

Comment: Your have a bad data structure.  The column `player` has the same value, shared between two tables.

Comment: Using `LOWER(bank.player)` in the `WHERE` clause prevents using the index (if there is one). Maybe you should use case-insensitive collation, then you can just write `WHERE bank.player = "verro"`

Comment: At least in ANSI SQL double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. column names), like `"bank"."item"`. String literals have single quotes, like `'verro'`.

Answer (score 1):

Because all the info you need is in the bank table, you don't need your join. Just run a query like this:

```
SELECT player, COUNT(id) 
FROM bank
WHERE player = 'verro' AND
item = 'gold bar'
```

And you should get what you need. In fact, the way your tables are set up, the player table is redundant with the info in bank table.